# How to make WholeCellGroupOpener menu shortcut that toggles

Tags: keyboard, menu

I put the following code using the Xcode application into an init.m file that is auto-loaded at startup. I can now turn on WholeCellGroupOpeners using a shortcut.  Works great.

```
FrontEndExecute[
 AddMenuCommands[
  "DuplicatePreviousOutput", {Delimiter, 
   MenuItem["OffWholeCellGroupOpener", 
    FrontEndExecute[
     SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], "WholeCellGroupOpener" -> True]],
     MenuKey["w", Modifiers -> {"Control"}], 
    System`MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]}]]
```

I would like to make the control more usable by making the same Control+w toggle between True and False states.

I tried substituting in

```
 "WholeCellGroupOpener" -> !CurrentValue@Options[SelectedNotebook[], "WholeCellGroupOpener"]
```

For some reason this code works as expected inside a regular .nb file but fails to work in the init.m file where I need it.  Any ideas?  Does it have something to do with global namespaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work.  Not sure why the other way doesn't.  I'll leave this solution up for reference.

```
"WholeCellGroupOpener" ->If[SameQ[CurrentValue[SelectedNotebook[],"WholeCellGroupOpener"],False],True,False]
```